# I can't boot elementary OS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub

I have bought a new pc. It has an Intel g3258 with an ASUS h81m-k mobo. I have installed Windows 10 ( with safe mode disabled) and I also want to install elementary OS.

But I'm not being able to install it. I have tried both 0.3.1 and 0.3.0. With the latest release, grub loads into bash minimal mode. With the old release grub doesn't install.

I have tried the answer I found in the forum, renaming grub files and it doesn't work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try going through this blog as well as the featured comment.

[Guide to install elementary along side windows](http://itsfoss.com/guide-install-elementary-os-luna/)

This explains "grub-efi could not install error"